# Regex to clean data from text between delimiters

Tags: c#, regex

I have some data that I want to process. It looks something like this:

```
[data]3456[/data]df[data]3424[/data]33[data]4324[/data]2214[data]3421[/data].. goes on
```

Anything between `[/data]` & `[data]` tags is just filler that I need to remove before the data can be used further. So I'm basically trying to remove `df`, `33` & `2214` in the above case. I'm trying to use a regex but I don't have a lot of experience using them. The data is in a `.txt` file and is read line by line. Any help will be appreciated!

```
while((line = reader.ReadLine()) !=null)
{
writer.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(line, ?? ,));
}
```

**Small edit to the question: 
This scenario is also possible:**

```
[data]3456[/data]456
435[data]4532[/data]
```

What to do in such a case?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @stribizhev `[data]3456[/data][data]3424[/data][data]4324[/data][data]3421[/data]` for the sample input above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Approach 1

We just collect all `[data]...[/data]`:

```
// Declare the regex as a private static readonly field
private static readonly Regex rx = new Regex(@"\[data\].*?\[/data\]", RegexOptions.Compiled);
// and then in the caller ....
writer.WriteLine(string.Join(string.Empty, rx.Matches(line).Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Value).ToArray()));
```

## Approach 2

You can use the following regex for a search & replace operation:

```
[^[\]]*(\[data\][^[]*\[/data\])[^[\]]*
```

With `$1` as replacement.

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5e%5b%5c%5d%5d*(%5c%5bdata%5c%5d%5b%5e%5b%5d*%5c%5b%2fdata%5c%5d)%5b%5e%5b%5c%5d%5d*&i=3456%5bdata%5d3456%5b%2fdata%5d456%0d%0a435%5bdata%5d4532%5b%2fdata%5d&r=%241), the result is `[data]3456[/data][data]3424[/data][data]4324[/data][data]3421[/data]` (for Input 1) or `[data]3456[/data][data]4532[/data]` for Input 2 (see *Context* tab).

In C#:

```
writer.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(line, @"[^[\]]*(\[data\][^[]*\[/data\])[^[\]]*", "$1"));
```

## Approach 3

Alternatively, you can use `Regex.Split` with further `string.Join()`:

```
var splts = Regex.Split(line, @"(?<=\[data\].*?\[/data\]).*?(?=\[data\]|$)");
writer.WriteLine(string.Join("", splts));
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/a4w8uM)

Comment: So `(Regex.Replace(line, @"<(\[data\][^[]*\[/data\])[^[\]]*>", "<$1>"))` ?

Comment: No, `"$1"` is the replacement pattern. In case you have more complex strings, with non-word symbols, you can try an alternative solution with `Regex.Split` and `string.Join`.

Comment: Hey, check edit in post. One small change in requirements that I just discovered in my data

Comment: Do you mean you might have multiline input? Please check my update. Actually, the [my first solution is working well, too](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5c%5bdata%5c%5d%5b%5e%5b%5d*%5c%5b%2fdata%5c%5d)%5b%5e%5b%5c%5d%5d*&i=%5bdata%5d3456%5b%2fdata%5d456%0d%0a435%5bdata%5d4532%5b%2fdata%5d&r=%241).

Comment: Yes, input could be multiline, also a data file could start with filler as well.. for example, `324[data]3335[/data]930[data]222[/data]....`

Comment: What about the `Regex.Split` solution? I have re-added it. You cannot have linebreaks, since you are processing line by line, as far as I see. With `[data]3456[/data]456435[data]4532[/data]` as input, I have just got `[data]3456[/data][data]4532[/data]`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83219/discussion-between-stribizhev-and-sparta93).

Comment: Looks like I got it: see Approach 1, I'd prefer that one.

Comment: Which approach do you think is the fastest?

Comment: @sparta93: If the regex object is compiled before its use, I'd use the first.

Answer (score 2):

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("[data]3456[/data]df[data]3424[/data]33[data]4324[/data]2214[data]3421[/data]",
    @"(?<=\[/data\]).*?(?=\[data\])", string.Empty));
```

Replace the value between `[/data]` and `[data]`